# Which devices support which traits?

Tags: nest-device-access

Is there a table somewhere of which devices support which traits?  I'm particularly interested in humidity:

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/humidity

But temp would be cool too, and I can convince myself ~most smart devices would have some awareness of temperature to shut down before they overheat etc.

I suspect humidity is just in the thermostats (not suitable for how we do HVAC here in AU) but I'm holding out hope it might also be in the smoke detectors... although they're not listed on the [devices page](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access). Even under the [old API](https://developers.nest.com/guides/api/smoke-co-guide) it looks like they didn't offer much (for example, it'd be awesome if you could get the motion detector state, or last motion detector trigger event from the nightlight feature).

Has anyone played around with the API enough to know? I'm only really interested in temp and humidity on the current list, so don't want to shell out the registration fee if they're not going to be available on my doorbell + smoke detectors + home hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Device Access docs don't list devices per trait, but they do list traits per device:

- [Camera](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/camera)
- [Thermostat](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat)
- [Doorbell](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/doorbell)
- [Display](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/display)

Today the only device type supporting the Humidity trait is Thermostats.

Comment: Thanks Ethan - I wondered if that was the case, but that would mean only the Thermostat has the Connectivity trait. Does that sound believable to you? I was hoping it's an error in the docs but that's probably more wishful thinking!

Comment: From making some test API calls the docs appear to be correct.